# How to get list of keys and their types from an object with Flow

Tags: flowtype

In other words,

I would like the flow equivalent of the following from typescript:

```
keyof typeof colors
```

How would I achieve this in Flow?

I tried this but it fails to build:

```
// @flow

const colors: Colors = {
    quillGrey: '#d9d9d6',
    sunsetOrange: '#F9423A'
};

type Colors = $Keys<typeof colors>;

export default colors;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why `colors` has type `Color` and at the same time `Color` is assigned the type of keys in `colors`. Something like next one should work:

```
const colors = {
  quillGrey: '#d9d9d6',
  sunsetOrange: '#F9423A'
}

type ColorsKeys = $Keys<typeof colors>;

export default colors;
```

And then `ColorsKeys` can be used as a type for keys in the `colors`.

Check here: [Try with flow](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBKA2IBOEYF4YG8BQM8wEcBXAS3ngHEkBTATwC4YByAYgBMBOTtgNiYBpc+CEUjUoAeSQBDMAHNqjVgDEOAFgBMAZgCCTbAF8hebFFoAHajADCIRCgDSdVBgAkT2hAA8ZyyABmcHbIEAB8ANzY2AAUTMRklDS0TIy29hAeEACUkbEiYpIy8tQpNsGOzjlRAPTVMACiSEjIMNQAHpbAUNRsMUzd0B6laSGZOUA)